# Draw a cone in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

How could I do something like this in TikZ?

[image]

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. I.e. which part are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Define a circle, construct the tangent point via the tangent coordinate system, transform the circle to an ellipse and apply the same transformation to the tangent point, draw the ellipse and the tangents.